# Display the error message once inside a DO block in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Hi i have 2 models related to one another:

**ProjectProcurementManagementPlan** `has_many: items`

**Item** `belongs_to :project_procurement_management_plan`

`project_procurement_management_plan.rb`:

```
class ProjectProcurementManagementPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :attachment, :agency_id, :user_id, :year, :status, :code, :prepared_by, 
                  :submitted_by, :items_attributes, :pmo_end_user, :attachments_attributes,
                  :category_id, :combine_in_app, :mode_of_procurement_id, :contract_type_id, 
                  :estimated_budget, :created_at, :updated_at, :currency

  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy, :order=>"created_at ASC"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:category_id].blank? }, 
                                        :allow_destroy => true

  validate :equality, :reduce=>true

  def equality
    self.items.each do |item|
    errors.add(:base, "Quantity must be equal to the breakdown of quantity!") if item.months != item.qty
    end
  end
end
```

`item.rb`:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :description, :estimated_budget, 
                  :project_procurement_management_plan_id, :quantity, :unit, :category_id, 
                  :combine_in_app, :mode_of_procurement_id, :contract_type_id, :january, 
                  :february, :march, :april, :may, :june, :july, :august, :september, :october, 
                  :november, :december

  belongs_to :project_procurement_management_plan

  def months
     total = january + february + march + april + may + june + july + august + 
             september + october + november + december
  end

  def qty
     self.quantity
  end
end
```

Since I am passing actions from item to the other model, I'm using `self`.  The validation is in the project procurement management plan file.  I am also aware that the `each do` block in the first model's `equality` method is the reason why I have multiple / redundant error display messages.  Is there any way to pass actions from model to model without using the `each do` block?

I tried:

```
def equality
    item = self.items
    errors.add(:base, "Quantity must be equal to the breakdown of quantity!") if item.months != item.qty
end
```

But no luck. It says `undefined method 'months'`.  Or is there any way to just display the error message once, though it is inside the `each do` block.

**PS: I am using cocoon for the nested attributes (items)**

Thanks. Any workarounds will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should validate the items in `Item` model itself, it will help you to catch up which items have the validation errors. But in case you just want to associate the error to `ProjectProcurementManagementPlan` you can do this way:

```
def equality
  self.items.each do |item|
    if item.months != item.qty
      errors.add(:base, "Quantity must be equal to the breakdown of quantity!")
      return
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

For Displaying the error message once, u can try :

```
def equality
    self.items.each do |item|
    unless errors.find.include?("Quantity must be equal to the breakdown of quantity!")
    {
    errors.add(:base, "Quantity must be equal to the breakdown of quantity!") if item.months != item.qty && errors.!include?
    break
    }
    end
  end
```

Comment: what if the first item has the accurate value but not the second or third.

Comment: what is `errors.!include?` for? And one more thing, this way you'll have to iterate each item. If there are 10 items and the 2nd item has wrong quantity then why would you loop through other 8 items, you should break the loop when you find the first incorrect/wrong quantity. See my answer.